# shared_from_this throws an exception

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am writing Qt-based app with Blender-like functionality.

It consists of a 'framework' which is GUI + plugin system and plugins. Plugins are Qt dlls with objects (e.g. a Sphere, a Box, etc.) that can be basically created and displayed. All those objects, once created, are stored in the framework in some kind of a container structure which holds shared_ptr's to them (so actually the container is pretty much like `vector<shared_ptr<INode>>`)

What I want is to use shared_from_this() function inside one of plugins.
E.g. Here's a sample plugin (code changed for clarity):

```
class Q_DECL_IMPORT SphereNode: public INode, public Sphere
```

Where `INode` is:

```
class INode: public QObject, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<INode>
```

,a base class for everything stored in the container. So the problem is that this function:

```
void SphereNode::update()
{
 foo(shared_from_this());
}
```

throws a `boost::bad_weak_ptr` exception.

A couple of notes how this SphereNode is created (a Factory class)

```
boost::shared_ptr<INode> NodeFactory::createNode(const QString& type, QString tag)
{
...
QPluginLoader loader(filesPlugin_[i]);
boost::shared_ptr<QObject> plugin(loader.instance());
boost::shared_ptr<INode> iNodePlugin = boost::shared_dynamic_cast<INode>(plugin);
return iNodePlugin;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note: I wouldn't use shared pointers on QObjects, if the user of your class sets a parent, you will run into double deletion problems, as both the shared pointer and the parent will delete the object when being deleted themselves.

Comment: @Frank: Are you sure of that ? I thought `QObject`s were smart enough to free their reference from their parents upon deletion.

Comment: ereOn: Yes, if the shared pointer comes first, the parent will notice.
But if the parent deletes the child first, the shared pointer will also delete the object -> double deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is this line:

```
boost::shared_ptr<INode> iNodePlugin = boost::shared_dynamic_cast<INode>(plugin);
```

Which should be replaced by:

```
boost::shared_ptr<INode> iNodePlugin = dynamic_cast<INode*>(loader.instance())->shared_from_this();
```

---

Maybe it has something to do with:

```
boost::shared_ptr<QObject> plugin(loader.instance());
```

Here `plugin` takes ownership of the returned instance. However, the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qpluginloader.html#instance) states that the instance will be automatically freed by the `QPluginLoader` upon destruction.

However, this would rather cause a segfault (undefined behavior) than a regular `boost::bad_weak_ptr` exception.

If you want to prevent this, you can specify a `null_deleter` that will do nothing when the reference counter reachs 0.

---

Are you calling `shared_from_this()` from either a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly) ?

If so, there is your problem.

When you're in the constructor, the object is not fully created yet, so having a `shared_ptr` to it is invalid.

To avoid this issue, you can get your `shared_ptr` to the object in a factory method (that you already have anyway), when the object was succesfully constructed.

Comment: Nope. First I create SphereNode with NodeFactory::createNode, then put it into the container, then call SphereNode::update(). So the constructor was called long ago before the actual call of shared_from_this()

Comment: @Mikhail: Added some elements to my answer. Not sure it helps though. Will continue to think about it.

Comment: Thanks, I also think it's something with the ownership.
Besides, is it okay that the first shared_ptr I create is shared_ptr<QObject>, where QObject is not inherited from boost::enable_shared_from_this? Can it be the reason why the weak_ptr inside enable_shared_from_this is null?

Comment: @Mikhail: I think this could definitely has something to do with. Check my (again updated ;) answer. I added a workaround that you might try.

Comment: Thanks a lot ereOn, it really solved the problem:
instead of boost::shared_ptr<QObject> plugin(loader.instance());
I should have used boost::shared_ptr<INode> plugin(dynamic_cast<INode*>(loader.instance())) :)